# Unsupported driver [ ] in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, server, driver

i am facing issue of unsupported driver while hitting my API i have following configurations in my config/database.php

```
        'mysql' => [
        'driver' => env('DB_CONNECTION'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
      //  'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
          ],
```

and my env file

```
            DB_CONNECTION=mysql
           DB_HOST=someURLsomeUrl
           DB_PORT=3306
         DB_DATABASE=ovadahealth_dev
        DB_USERNAME=ovadahealth_user
         DB_PASSWORD=password
```

I have spent an hours in this issue and i cant find out where is the issue when i hit my api in postman it says:

```
 {
"status": false,
"message": "Unsupported driver []"
}
```

Here your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: A tips, dont send, and publish your credentials.

Comment: Delete and reask this question! ur credentials are still seen in the edit history

Comment: The `driver` really shouldn't be dynamic in your config.  This section is clearly for a mysql driver, so there's no point to having driver be filled from an environmental variable.  I would recommend just pulling down the default database.php config file from Laravel and see if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. use php artisan config:clear to clear your configuration.